# Display image using CSS in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In MVC 2 I'm trying to display a image On my master page using CSS.

```
.menu .symbol-item  { background-image:url(Content/icons/page.png); }
```

The image is displaying when the URL is like

```
http://localhost:4745/Item
```

but it does not display when the URL is like

```
 http://localhost:4745/Item/Create
```

Both the pages use the same master page

Comment: Use an absolute path: `.menu .symbol-item  { background-image:url(/Content/icons/page.png); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Url.Content` in order to make sure your URL will resolve to the same place every time. To do this, that CSS needs to live in your view. First move it to your view, then do:

```
.menu .symbol-item  { background-image:url(@Url.Content("~/Content/icons/page.png"); }
```

Comment: did not work. I used .menu .symbol-item  { background-image:url(<%: Url.Content("~/Content/icons/page.png")%>); } but still the same result

Comment: @chamara what was the URL for the image in the browser? Check dev tools.